# undefined method 'admin?' for #<User:0x007fccda8003c8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancancan

I am using `gem 'devise'` and `'cancancan'` for defining  many roles per user. problem is when I run rails server its says `undefined method admin?`

in application_controller.rb file:

```
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up)  { |u| u.permit(:roles) }
  end
```

in user.rb file :

```
  ROLES = %i[admin author]

  def roles=(roles)
    roles = [*roles].map { |r| r.to_sym }
    self.roles_mask = (roles & ROLES).map { |r| 2**ROLES.index(r) }.inject(0, :+)
  end

  def roles
    ROLES.reject do |r|
      ((roles_mask.to_i || 0) & 2**ROLES.index(r)).zero?
    end
  end

  def has_role?(role)
    roles.include?(role)
  end
```

in ability.rb file :

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

any idea ??

Comment: I guess your `users` table doesn't have column `admin`. Please check your migrations any pending or add it accordingly.

Comment: Unrelated, but `roles = [*roles].map(&:to_sym)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `User` model doesn't have an `admin?` method. Instead it provides a `has_role?` method. So instead of `user.admin?` write in your `ability.rb`:

```
user.has_role?(:admin)
```

An other option is add an `admin?` method to your `User` model:

```
def admin?
  has_role?(:admin)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add method admin? to the user.rb

```
def admin?
  self.roles.include?(:admin)
end
```

or try to call has_role?(:admin) from the ability.rb file.